# ActiveAdmin: load and use models from other engine doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-engines

I followed the guide in the wiki to use my models from my engine in my main-app with active admin.

The only thing I must change (that doesn't mentioned in the wiki) was this:

```
if defined?(ActiveAdmin)
  ActiveAdmin.register Blog::Category do
  end
end
```

I just added: `Blog::`.
In my engine "Blog" I added a model named "category" with a name:string attribute. But when I add one in active admin the field name wasn't saved in the database. My request parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PzKDTcoJZ6Sy2tXgw9WSwXiR7aZp81lOtBvfD5Ec3F72H5L7MEMLjlOFgKWQBo2U4n9mPc7AgjcIS3MTIY2nZA==", "category"=>{"name"=>"asdasd"}, "commit"=>"Update Category", "id"=>"1"}
```

any ideas why it isn't saved in the databse? 
When I create a new one, the record is created but without my input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. I was able to get the resources to save properly by overriding the activeadmin controller actions (in e.g. app/admin/category.rb) like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Blog::Category do

  permit_params :the, :parameters, :for, :your, :resource

  controller do
    def create
      @category = Blog::Category.new permitted_params[:category]
      if @category.save
        notice = 'Category was successfully created.'
        redirect_to admin_blog_category_url(@category), notice: notice
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure exactly what's going on in the default case yet, but my guess is that the activeadmin controller action is not creating the object in the right namespace - that is, it does something like `@category = Category.new` rather than `@category = Blog::Category.new`. A similar override appears to be necessary for the `:update` action as well.

Comment: any idea why the validations are not working? I'll getting all the time a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::BlogDocumentsController#create`. I think AA is skipping my validations..